# Rename [extreme] tag to [extreme-conditions] or remove it

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are currently 3 questions tagged with [extreme](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/extreme):
One relates to extreme temperatures, the second to extreme tabbed browsing (massive pressure on the computer), and the third to temperatures and extreme cooling.

Should we rename the tag (maybe to [extreme-conditions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/extreme-conditions)), or remove it? I think it might be useful, even though it's rare, in some cases. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

It's garbage, I removed it from the 3 questions. Time will do the rest.

Comment: Okay. That was quick :)